# How to PARTITION BY to show the same value for all rows?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, alias, partition-by

I have a listing of all consumer purchases where some consumers make many purchases over the time frame in scope. I'd like to populate a column with the location of each consumer's first purchase but I'm getting this error:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '(' expecting <EOF>(line 2, pos 25)

== SQL ==
SELECT consumer_id
       ,location OVER(partition BY table.consumer_id) AS first_purchase_site
---------------------^^^
FROM table
```

For clarity, here is my query:

```
SELECT consumer_id
       ,location OVER(partition BY table.consumer_id) AS first_purchase_site
FROM table
WHERE consumer_purchase_order_sequence = 1
```

Comment: You should use window functions

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html

Comment: partition by works with aggregate functions. you can not use `location over()`. Pls use this `SELECT consumer_id        ,location from ( SELECT a.*, row_number() OVER(partition BY table.consumer_id) AS rn from Table a) rs WHERE rs.rn=1 `

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to populate a column with the location of each consumer's first purchase

Are you looking for `first_value()`?

```
SELECT consumer_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(location) OVER (partition BY table.consumer_id) AS first_purchase_site
FROM table;
```

Your window function is, errr, missing the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need window function `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT consumer_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(location) OVER(PARTITION BY consumer_id ORDER BY consumer_purchase_order_sequence) AS first_purchase_site
FROM table
```

Change `consumer_purchase_order_sequence` with the column that orders the purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to do it with window calculations .You can do it with joins,

```
SELECT 
  table.consumer_id,
  table.location,
  a.first_purchase_site
FROM table LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT consumer_id,location AS first_purchase_site FROM table WHERE 
  consumer_purchase_order_sequence = 1) a ON a.consumer_id=table.consumer_id
```